# is it possible to scan 10 images at once ocr using google vision api? so far manage to do only 1

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-vision

We are currently doing an ocr project using google vision API where the images return a text value... but so far we manage to do only 1 image, is it possible to do 10 images? im using python and this code only runs one image.. thank you

```
import os, io
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
import pandas as pd

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r'anjir.json'

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

FILE_NAME = 'receipttest2.jpg'
FOLDER_PATH = r'C:\Users\Fadhlan\Desktop\Python venv\image\text'

with io.open(os.path.join(FOLDER_PATH, FILE_NAME), 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
response = client.text_detection(image=image)
texts = response.text_annotations

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['locale', 'description'])
for text in texts:
    df = df.append(
        dict(
            locale=text.locale,
            description=text.description
        ),
        ignore_index=True

    )
print(df['description'][0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using [batch image annotation offline](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/batch) since the ["TEXT_DETECTION" feature](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/batch#currently_supported_feature_types) is supported in the asynchronous mode. You can find a sample code for Python [in here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/batch#sample_code) and as you can see there, it's required to create a request element for each image and add it to the array of requests:

```
client = vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient()

//image one
source1 = {"image_uri": image_uri_1}
image1 = {"source": source1}
features1 = [
    {"type": enums.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION},
    {"type": enums.Feature.Type.IMAGE_PROPERTIES}
]

//image two
source2 = {"image_uri": image_uri_2}
image2 = {"source": source2}
features2 = [
    {"type": enums.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION}
]

# Each requests element corresponds to a single image
requests = [{"image": image1, "features": features1}, {"image": image2, "features": features2}]
gcs_destination = {"uri": output_uri}

# The max number of responses to output in each JSON file
batch_size = 2

output_config = {"gcs_destination": gcs_destination,
                 "batch_size": batch_size}
operation = client.async_batch_annotate_images(requests, output_config)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help... but can you give a little example on how to create a request element for each image and add it to the array of requests

Comment: I have edited my answer showing an example for two images.

Comment: alright thank you sir.... but can i know what is image_uri, gcs_destination and batch_size?