# How batch image annotation offline works? from Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ocr

Does anyone know how the badge image annotation offline works? We are currently doing projects for OCR where we want to scan 10 images at once and it prints out 10 output , it would be helpful if anyone could share anything about this. Thank you.

Sample code:

```
import os, io
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
import pandas as pd

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r'anjir.json'

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

FILE_NAME = 'receipttest2.jpg'
FOLDER_PATH = r'C:\Users\Fadhlan\Desktop\Python venv\image\text'

with io.open(os.path.join(FOLDER_PATH, FILE_NAME), 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
response = client.text_detection(image=image)
texts = response.text_annotations

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['locale', 'description'])
for text in texts:
    df = df.append(
        dict(
            locale=text.locale,
            description=text.description
        ),
        ignore_index=True
    )
print(df['description'][0])
```

Badge image annotation offline from Google Cloud:

```
from google.cloud.vision_v1 import enums


def sample_async_batch_annotate_images(
    input_image_uri="gs://cloud-samples-data/vision/label/wakeupcat.jpg",
    output_uri="gs://your-bucket/prefix/",
):
    """Perform async batch image annotation."""
    client = vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    source = {"image_uri": input_image_uri}
    image = {"source": source}
    features = [
        {"type": enums.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION},
        {"type": enums.Feature.Type.IMAGE_PROPERTIES},
    ]

    # Each requests element corresponds to a single image.  To annotate more
    # images, create a request element for each image and add it to
    # the array of requests
    requests = [{"image": image, "features": features}]
    gcs_destination = {"uri": output_uri}

    # The max number of responses to output in each JSON file
    batch_size = 2
    output_config = {"gcs_destination": gcs_destination,
                     "batch_size": batch_size}

    operation = client.async_batch_annotate_images(requests, output_config)

    print("Waiting for operation to complete...")
    response = operation.result(90)

    # The output is written to GCS with the provided output_uri as prefix
    gcs_output_uri = response.output_config.gcs_destination.uri
    print("Output written to GCS with prefix: {}".format(gcs_output_uri))
```

Comment: Can you please better describe your issue? What do you want to accomplish? It is impossible to do OCR in GCP offline, since GCP is cloud computing.

Comment: actually we are trying to print out  text from 10 different image which, where 10 output will be produced .... and in previous question we also asked the same thing and this user stated that the badge image annotation offline can be used in order to do this.  -

Comment: Can you please point to the previous question you are referring to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is it possible to scan 10 images at once ocr using google vision api? so far manage to do only 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371192/is-it-possible-to-scan-10-images-at-once-ocr-using-google-vision-api-so-far-man)

Comment: no not really will try